# Routing agents through specific resources in anylogic

Tags: anylogic, job-scheduling

I am solving a job shop scheduling problem resorting to anylogic. I have 20 jobs (agents) and 5 machines(resources) and each job as a specific order to visit the machines. My question is: how can I make sure that each job follows its order.

[This is what I have done. One agent called 'jobs' and 5 agents, each one corresponding to a machine. One resource pool associated to each one of the service blocks. In the collection enterblocks I selected the 5 enter blocks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxGcX.png)

[In the agent 'jobs' I have this. The parameters associated to each job, read from the database file, and the collection 'enternames' where I selected the machine(1,2,3,4,5) parameters and the collection 'ptimes' where I put the processing times of the job (This two colletions is where I am not sure I have done it correctly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqKVj.png)

[My database file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MSty.png)

I am not sure how to use the counter used here [How to store routings in job shop production in Anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158916/how-to-store-routings-in-job-shop-production-in-anylogic). In the previous link the getNextService function is used in the exit blocks but I am also not sure how to use it in my case due to the counter.

Comment: Hi, this place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question if far too broad and would need a full lecture to tell you all about it. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focussed on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a reply :)

Comment: I have a database that consists in 20 lines (each one corresponds to a job) and 10 columns (machine sequence and the processing time corresponding to each machine). I want to do the job shop scheduling but I don't know how to assign each job to the machines in the order given in the file. I am doing what is in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158916/how-to-store-routings-in-job-shop-production-in-anylogic but i have some question about how using the collections.

Comment: I made some editions to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to confirm that based on the *Job* agent and database view, the first line in the database will result in a *Job* agent with values such as:

1. `machine1 = 1` and `process1=23`
2. `machine2 = 0` and `process2=82` and so on

If that is the intent, then a better way is to restructure the database, so there are two tables:

1. Table of jobs to machine sequence looking something like this:

| job | op1 | op2 | op3 | op4 | op5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | machine2 | machine1 | machine4 | machine5 | machine3 |
| 2 | machine4 | machine3 | machine5 | machine1 | machine2 |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

2. Table of jobs to processing time

Then, add a collection of type `ArrayList` of `String` to **Job** (let's call this collection `col_machineSequence`) and when the **Job** agents get created their `on startup` code should be:

```java
   for (String param : List.of("op1","op2","op3","op4","op5")) {
       col_machineSequence.add(getParameter(param));
   }
```

As a result, `col_machineSequence` will contain sequence of machines each job should visit in the order defined in the database.

NOTE: Please see [help on getParameter() here](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)).

Also:

1. Putting a **Queue** in front of the **Service** isn't necessary
2. Repeating **Enter**-**Queue**-**Service**-**Exit** isn't necessary, this can be simplified using [this method](https://youtu.be/0Nu1a9Te6ac?t=76)

---

Follow-up clarifications:

1. Collections - these will be enclosed in each **Job** agent
2. Queue sorting - **Service** block has **Priorities / preemption** which governs the ordering on the queue
3. Create another agent for the second table (call the agent **ProcessingTime** and table `processing_time`) and add it to the **Job** agent and then load it from database filtering on `p_jobid` as shown in the picture

[image]

Comment: Ok I think I got it mas I still have some questions. I should create 2 collection like you suggested, one for the sequences and the other for the processing times right? Another question is, i am going to have as many colletions as the number of agent I have right? Or it is just one that includes everything? For last, I have a queue in front of service because I will order the jobs in relation to their processing times, or I can do that in the service block? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Oh another question :) i should still use the collection enterblocks in the way I am currenty using it?

Comment: I am so sorry, using to DB tables I can only associate one of them to the agent Jobs...

Comment: @RodrigoLemos, please always open new questions if you have ... new questions. Check how StackOverflow works, it is not a forum (back'n'forth comms) but a pure Q&A place :)

Comment: I will add clarification to my answer, but it is better if you add a separate question if it is still unclear and you need more help.

Comment: I add a new question, hope it is understandable

Comment: Ok, please could you mark this question as 'answered'?