# How to send agents through exit and enter blocks?

Tags: anylogic, job-scheduling

I am trying to do a job shop scheduling resorting to anylogic. I have 20 jobs(Agent 'jobs') that have to go through 5 machines(each one a unit capacity resource). I have two database tables, one having the specific order of each job through the machines and the other one has the processing times of the jobs in the respectives machines.

[This is what I have right now. The source creates the 20 jobs and I want that the exit blocks sent the jobs through their sequence. I made the 'nextmachine' function that I put in the On Exit section in each one of the exit blocks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DYV3.png)

[This is my 'nextmachine' function and the error I keep getting and don't know how to solve. Enterblocks is a collection of class ArrayList and element class Agent that have the 5 enter blocks and the col_machineSequence is a collection with each job machine sequence.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNHND.png)

The 'nextmachine' code was based in this post [How to store routings in job shop production in Anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158916/how-to-store-routings-in-job-shop-production-in-anylogic).

I made a question previously [Routing agents through specific resources in anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162407/routing-agents-through-specific-resources-in-anylogic/68177036#68177036). Here you can see some of my previous doubts and some of the suggestions.

Thank you in advance

[The enterblocks collection is in the jobs agent, and is defined in this way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECIb6.png)

-New Error:[I have this error, I think it is related with collection col_machineSequence.I have that code onStartup section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA8AL.png)

Comment: Can please you show the type of collection - agent.enterblocks? where is it in the model and how is it populated?

Comment: Cool I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the *Elements class* property of `enterblocks` collections needs to be changed to `Enter`. To do this, select 'Other' in the dropdown and type `Enter` into the field that will appear to the right of the dropdown.

Comment: It worked, but now I am getting one big error. Please see my latest edition.

Comment: ok, you have to populate `col_machineSequence` inside the job agent as it should be referring to op1, op2, etc parameters that are loaded from the jobs table into each job agent.

Comment: Isn't it already inside the job agent? I think I didn't understand I am sorry

Comment: Ah yes it is, apologies for confusion. The error is occurring in `findFirst` call. This can happen when no match is found for which there can be 2 reasons: `col_machineSequence` is empty or contains wrong values. Hence, first test is to check what is populated in `col_machineSequence`, for that add a 'traceln' to see what values are being added. Second test is to check what name it is looking for, so do add `traceln`  in `findFirst` call.